# How do IP camera stream video across home network

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming

My question is how do the IP camera stream the data from home network to public network. Here's how I think it can be done:

1. If I'd to set up something like this using a raspberry pi camera module. I'd probably use port forwarding on my Access Point/Wifi Router. However, clearly, this is not a scalable solution, and there must be something else that off the shelf IP cameras must be doing.
2. One option is to stream the video (using ffmpeg) to a remove server, and then that remote server can probably again "re-stream" that? -If this is indeed the case, how is it done?

I understand backend architecture very strongly, and have developed fairly complex onces so I do want a fairly technical answer for this one.

Comment: The answer here depends greatly on your *specific needs*, which you haven't told us about.  How many viewers at a time will there be?  What are the quality and latency requirements?  Is there audio too?  What client compatibility is required?  If you're just making a DIY wireless doorbell, WebRTC P2P with a minimal signalling server is fine.  If you're streaming the Olympics, you're going to need to interface with a CDN, among 1,000 other issues.

Comment: Its never going to be over 2-3 people at the same time. Also, average quality and 2-3 sec latency is okay. Its DIY project

Comment: And, the answers to all the other questions?  Or should I just assume what you need?

Comment: Okay, no Audio. Client compatibility - should stream on browser if possible

Comment: @brad, I need to understand what the over the shelf IP camera companies do, so its not really what I need, its mostly how they do it. I'm sure what I've specified in my comments are pretty close to the assumptions that these IP camera companies assume

Answer (score 0):

Use WebRTC, for the following reasons:

- **Peer-to-Peer Connectivity.**  Avoid having to pay for a streaming media server just to relay to a couple people, if the source can do it on its own.
- **NAT Traversal.**  In most cases (~87% of the time), it's possible for UPnP to punch a hole, or for one of the peers to not be firewalled.  Therefore, a direct connection can be made.  In the event it cannot, a TURN server can proxy the data between the peers.  All of this connectivity negotiation is part of ICE, and is handled for you by WebRTC clients.
- **Codec Negotiation.**  No need to worry about what's supported by which client.  The WebRTC stack negotiates all of this for you, and also dictates some common codecs that all WebRTC clients support... so you should never have a case where there isn't at least some profile of some codec that works.
- **Low Latency.**  WebRTC was designed for video conferencing in-mind, and therefore prioritizes latency over quality and general reliability.  That is, if you lose your connection, it will pick right back up at the current time rather than trying to go back and figure out what happened 10 seconds ago.  For your latency targets, this is a good thing.
- **Browser Support.** There is broad browser support for WebRTC, with all major browsers as well as many other app libraries supporting it.

All of the good consumer IP cameras support WebRTC.  From an infrastructure standpoint, all they need to do is host a signalling server (which allows peers to communicate and negotiate their own connections initially), and a TURN server for the peers that cannot communicate directly together.  This is quite cheap.  The signalling servers take almost no load and bandwidth.  The TURN server isn't needed in most cases.  Additionally, there are *many* providers offering off-the-shelf WebRTC stacks, complete with client libraries.

Some IP cameras don't do this.  Some make users figure out what the IP address is, punch it in their browser or media player, and then stream MJPEG and similar.

Comment: OK. How would one implement it? Any links?

Comment: Gstreamer is useful for this.  For the web-based clients, check out everything on MDN.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Protocols

Comment: "so you should never have a case where there isn't at least some profile of some codec that works" -- that is unfortunately only true in theory. Apple choose to ignore that the VP8 codec is mandatory-to-implement. Consequently h264 woes apply.

Comment: @PhilippHancke To be fair, Google also ignores the mandatory-to-implement H.264 codec on Android when the device doesn't have a supported H.264 chip :)

Comment: @PhilippHancke Sure, and there's practically always an H.264 implementation available, even if it's some crappy baseline profile.  I've never seen an Android device without a hardware codec for H.264.  No doubt you could find me one somewhere, but you'll have plenty of other compatibility issues long before you have to worry about the ~5 people who use such a device.  In any case, of course we still need a compatible codec to send video to anyway... I'd rather leave it to the WebRTC stack to negotiate it, if that's a choice.

Comment: @Brad: I read more, and have come across Janus gw. I understand it can behave as signalling as well as turn server. So wouldn't I need Janus alongside gstreamer? Also, can you point me to any link where in a similar implementation is described, using gstreamer or uv4l doesn't matter, but which gives clear understanding of how to go about implementing this?